# Non-homogeneous forcing and HOD

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Is there a separative forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$ such that:

1) For any $p \in\mathbb{P}, \mathbb{P}/p = \{q \in \mathbb{P}: q \leq p  \}$ is not forcing isomorphic to any homogeneous forcing notion,

2) For all $G$, $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$, $HOD^{V[G]} \subseteq V$.

Here by homogeneity I mean cone homogeneity, i.e. for any p, q in 
 $\mathbb{P}$, there are $p' \leq p, q' \leq q$ and an isomorphism from  $\mathbb{P}/ p' $ onto  $\mathbb{P}/q'.$

Comment: Could you clarify precisely which notion of homogeneity you have in mind? There are some stronger versions, and some weaker versions. It is easy to make some examples with the stronger versions failing, but I don't yet have an example for the weak versions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You should also assume that $\mathbb{P}$ is separative, or use Boolean algebras, since every partial order is forcing equivalent to a non-cone-homogeneous partial order, simply by replacing each point with a (different cardinality) linear set, and this would enable some easy instances.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: Ah, actually, the need for separativity is obviated by the requirement in 1 that it is not "forcing isomorphic" to any homogeneous forcing notion.

Comment: By "forcing isomorphic", you mean that the regular open algebras are isomorphic?

Comment: Yes. I mean their regular open Boolean algebras are isomorphic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is consistent that the answer is positive and it is consistent that the answer is negative.

**Claim:** There is a generic extension, $V[G]$ by a weakly homogeneous forcing notion in which there is a rigid forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$ such that for every generic filter $H \subseteq \mathbb{P}$, $$HOD^V = HOD^{V[G]} = HOD^{V[G][H]}.$$

**Proof:** Let $\kappa$ be a regular uncountable cardinal. Recall that $\square(\kappa)$ sequence is a sequence $\mathcal{C} = \langle C_\alpha \mid \alpha < \kappa\rangle$ such that $C_\alpha \subseteq \alpha$ is a club, for every accumulation point $\beta \in \text{acc }C_\alpha$, $C_\beta = C_\alpha \cap \beta$ and there is no club $D \subseteq \kappa$ such that for every $\beta \in \text{acc }D$, $D \cap \beta = C_\beta$.

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be the forcing notion for adding a $\square(\kappa)$ sequence using bounded approximations (or successor ordinal length). Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the generic $\square(\kappa)$ sequence. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the forcing notion $\mathcal{C}$, where $C_\alpha$ is stronger than $C_\beta$ in the order of $\mathbb{P}$ if $C_\alpha$ is an end extension of $C_\beta$.

$\mathbb{S}$ is weakly homogeneous and $\mathbb{S} \ast \mathbb{P}$ has a dense subset isomorphic to the Cohen forcing $\text{Add}(\kappa, 1)$. Therefore the Boolean completion of $\mathbb{S} \ast \mathbb{P}$ is weakly homogeneous. On the other hand $\mathbb{P}$ is rigid. In fact, if $V[G] \subseteq W$ is a model of $ZFC$ and $H_1, H_2\in W$ are two distinct $V[G]$-generic filters for $\mathbb{P}$ then $W \models \text{cf }\kappa = \omega$.

By density arguments (on $\mathbb{S}$ and $\mathbb{P}$), $D_1 = \bigcup H_1,\ D_2 = \bigcup H_2$ are both *threads*, namely, for $i = 1, 2$ and every accumulation point $\beta\in \text{acc }D_i$, $D_i\cap \beta = C_\beta$. But if $\text{cf }\kappa$ is uncountable, then $\text{acc }D_1 \cap \text{acc }D_2$ is unbounded at $\kappa$ and therefore $D_1 = D_2$ and thus $H_1 = H_2$. This implies that there is no automorphism for the Boolean completion of $\mathbb{P}$ which is non-trivial on the generic filter, since this automorphism sends the generic filter to a different generic filter. Since $\mathbb{P}$ preserves the regularity of $\kappa$ - this is impossible.

**Claim:** Assume $V = L$. Then for every complete Boolean algebra $\mathbb{B}$, $\Vdash_{\mathbb{B}} HOD^{V[G]} = L$ iff for densely many $b\in \mathbb{B}$, $\mathbb{B} \restriction b$ is weakly homogeneous.

**Proof:** Let $$\mathbb{C} = \{ x \in \mathbb{B} \mid \forall \sigma \in \text{Aut}({\mathbb{B}}),\ \sigma(x) = x\}.$$

Where we take the set of all automorphisms that respect also arbitrary $\inf$ and $\sup$.

$\mathbb{C}$ is a complete subalgebra of $\mathbb{B}$. Let $G \subseteq \mathbb{B}$ be $L$-generic and let us claim that the generic filter for $\mathbb{C}$ belongs to $HOD^{V[G]}$.

Indeed, $b \in G\cap \mathbb{C}$ iff for every $L$-generic filter $H\subseteq \mathbb{B}$, $b\in H$. This follows from a theorem of Vopenka and Hajek:

**Theorem (Vopenka and Hajek):** If $H_1, H_2\subseteq \mathbb{B}$ are $V$-generic and $V[H_1] = V[H_2]$ then there is an automotphism $\sigma\in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{B})$ such that $\sigma '' H_1 = H_2$.

Thus, we conclude that $\Vdash \dot{G} \cap \mathbb{C}\in L$, and in particular, in $\mathbb{C}$ there is a dense set of atoms. Otherwise, there is $c\in \mathbb{C}$ such that there are no atoms below $c$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore, $G \cap \mathbb{C} \notin L$ for every generic filter $G$ that contains $c$, since it is a generic filter for non-atomic forcing. Let $a$ be an atom of $\mathbb{C}$. The forcing $\mathbb{B} \restriction a$ is weakly homogeneous, as for every $b \leq a$, the orbit of $b$, $\{\sigma(b) \mid \sigma \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{B})\}$ is below $a$, and therefore $\bigvee_{\sigma \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{B})} \sigma(b) = a$. Therefore, for every $c \leq a$, there is $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(b) \wedge c \neq 0$.